# How to get water from can into bottles with less effort?

Tags: water, container

Nowadays we are using water container as shown below for drinking water.

[image]

Suggest any hack to get water without either bending or [this](https://www.amazon.in/HUILE-Manual-bottled-water-Drinking/dp/B01LZPDJ9Y) manual motor.

Note that I have to exchange this water container daily with a filled one.

Comment: Do you have the skill to build something from a valve and a few plastic pipes? I can suggest a design if you want a really easy to use solution, but you'll need to make it with tools like a saw, drill, and glue. You can build something that works the same way as the water dispenser you could buy from a water company.

Comment: No, but if any video reference, then I can learn all those...

Answer (score 5):

You can use a rubber tube/small hose. Put one end in the water, suck out the air from the other end until the water starts flowing. To stop the water from flowing lift the tube above the level of the water in the tank or block the entrance with something.

Comment: Hanugm, this is called a siphon. You can Google that for videos and more instructions. @user18894, perfect answer. This is what I was going to say! +1

Comment: You don't have to suck it, if you consider it unhygienic.. use a long tube - at least twice as long as the can is high. Hold one end of the tube and put as much of the tube into the can as possible. Put your thumb/finger over the end you're holding, to block the end completely, then pull the tube about half way out of the can and lower the end you're holding so it is well below the level of the water in the can. Release your thumb to start the siphon

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the big water jug. First, it's gigantic and cumbersome. Second, the water doesn't pour out smoothly; it splashes everywhere in an uncontrollable "glug glug glug" fashion.

user18894's siphon answer is probably easiest, but you can also use a standard water pitcher as an intermediate container. A water pitcher has a big open top, so it doesn't matter how "inaccurately" the giant jug pours the water out. Once the water is in the manageable pitcher, it has a spout that makes it easy to pour accurately into your small bottles.

[image]

It *may* be useful to use a funnel to pour the water from the pitcher into your water bottles. That will depend on the design of the water pitcher's spout, and on the size of you water bottles' necks.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy taps that fit on the opening of these bottles. Look for "5 Gallon Water Jug Dispenser".

Example:
[image]

The image also shows a yoke you can place the bottle on. The yoke is easy enough to make yourself from wood. Building a tap that's watertight is a bit more complex:

- you need a removable and reusable cap for the bottle
- buy a tap
- drill a hole in the cap to fit the tap into
- make a watertight seal between the cap and the tap